# Get difference of current time and first value in a column in SQL/PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an SQL query in a Rails app where I'm trying to find the difference in time between the current time and the first incidence time was recorded in a column.

`now() - FIRST(product_selections.staged_at) as time_in_inventory`

SQL is not liking the use of `FIRST` here so far.

Originally in ActiveRecord this worked as:

```
def time_since_first_use
    product_selections.none? 
        ? "N/A" 
        : Time.now - product_selections.order(staged_at: :asc).first.staged_at
    end
```

HEre's the main query for reference:

```
SELECT 
    warehouses.name as warehouse_name, 
    products.name as product_name, 
    SUM(product_selections.use_time) as total_time_staged, 
    now() - FIRST(product_selections.staged_at) as time_in_inventory, 
FROM warehouses
    LEFT JOIN rfid_tags 
        ON warehouses.id = rfid_tags.location_id
        AND rfid_tags.location_type = 'Warehouse'
    LEFT JOIN products
        ON rfid_tags.ancestor_product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN category_assignments
        ON category_assignments.product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN categories
        ON category_assignments.category_id = categories.id
    LEFT JOIN product_selections
        ON product_selections.product_id = products.id          
WHERE 
    warehouses.id = 1063
    AND category_assignments.primary = true 
GROUP BY 
    warehouses.id,
    warehouses.name,
    categories.id,
    categories.name,
    products.name,
    products.working_value
HAVING COUNT(rfid_tags)>0
ORDER BY
    categories.name,
    products.name
```

Comment: Since you are sorting in ascending order by that column I think you are looking for `MIN(product_selections.staged_at)`

Comment: NOW() - MIN(product_selections.staged_at) seems to work...